# VB.Net HTTPWebRequest Speed is slow comparing Python URLOpen

Tags: python, vb.net, http, comparison

Hi I am coding a web-crawler which will crawl the websites and selectively parse different sections of a web site.

I am a .Net developer so the choice was obvious that I did it in .Net but the speed was very slow which included downloading and parsing of HTMLPages

Then I tried to just download the contents first using .Net and then same domains using python but the python was very impressive in downloading data. I have achieved downloading using python but the later part is not that easy to code in python, which obviously i don't want to do.

The same batch of domain which took 100 seconds in Python
was taking 20 minutes in .Net based crawler

I tried http://www.eqlit.com/ to download and in took 8 seconds in Python and same was taking 100 Seconds in .Net crawler

Does anyone anyone have any idea why this is slow in .Net but fast in python?

Comment: Care to share code sample how you implement the `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: I am not sure but it seems that python script is using http compression.

Comment: Sorry I can not publish code some company policy u know :)

Comment: From this discussion I want to know is there some compiler overhead which slow down the HTTP communication or are there some settings I can make to increase socket buffer or connection timeout or DNS resolution settings timeout etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpWebRequest is limited to 2 connections at a time, so if you're downloading content along with html (such as images, stylesheets, js etc.) or you are using multiple threads then you'll hit the connection limit.

you'll need to change the settings in ServicePointManager.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

This links explains what you need to do.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

you may also want to set these settings while you're at it.

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10; // for example
```

Another way is to use a config file for your app and use the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="10"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @shiv-kumar Thanks for your response this does help but there is a lot of different in output.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include config file settings as an alternative to setting the ServicePointManager property.

Comment: @regexhacks, are you calling Close() on your Response? Not doing so, keeps the connection open.

Comment: Also see if setting the KeepAlive to false helps. In your case you don't need it since you're moving on to other sites. myHttpWebRequest1.KeepAlive=false;

Comment: By output I mean the time taken by both crawlers